# Html Element wont load .png

Tags: html, angular, image, http

I received a 404 error and the image doesn't load. I'm quite sure that the path is correct

```
<img src="../assets/img/Logo.png" alt="Logo">
```

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t1AYf.png) you can see my Folder Structure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the image doesn't load, most likely the path is not correct.

Did you try `/assets/img/Logo.png`?

The other possible reason is a server misconfiguration, but I'm assuming that this error is occurring in the development server, so that wouldn't apply.

Comment: Yeah i tried many different ways but i always get the 404. Also my VS-Code suggest me the path you can see in the post

Comment: Really should be `assets/img/Logo.png` (without the initial `/`) for include the case of base href was different than "/". VS-Code suggest the path based in your folder structure, but Angular copy the assets folder in the same folder that create the index.html. So our paths should take account this folder, **not** the structure folder of our app.